# Can I add condition fields using queryDSL ? (like mybatis)

Tags: querydsl

Can I add condition fields using queryDSL ?

Example (case mybatis)

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM CAT
   WHERE
    age = 2
   <if test="cat.name eq 'navi'">
    AND address = 'ROMA' 
   </if>
```

I want like this, apply it to queryDsl

How to apply this ?

Now

```
 List<NumberPath<Long>> paths = new ArrayList();
 List<Long> values = new ArrayList<>();

 if (itemBox.getItemNo() > 0) {
            numberPaths.add(QItemBox.ItemNo);
            numberPathValues.add(itemBox.getItemNo());
       }

  update(QItemBox)
              .set(paths,values)
              .execute();
```

I'm currently using it like this, but it seems inefficient.
Is there any more efficient way? Please give me some advice.

Comment: Do you want to execute the conditional in Java or SQL?

Also, the query represents an update query but the example is a simple select query. Which ones would you like to see adjusted?>

Comment: I want to convert Mybtis conditional function to JAVA using QueryDSL